# Error gem omnicontacts ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to import contacts from gmail. I used the gem onmioutcontacts.

I have configured a file called in /config/initializers/onmicontacts.rb

require "omnicontacts"

Rails.application.middleware.use OmniContacts::Builder do
  importer :gmail, "client_id", "client_secret", {:redirect_path => "/contacts/callback"} 
end

but when I call from *[Import contacts from Gmail](/contacts/callback)*
gives me the following error:

Started GET "/contacts/callback" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-04 16:41:01 -0300
Error not_authorized while processing /contacts/callback: User did not grant access to contacts list

Started GET "/contacts/failure?error_message=not_authorized&importer=gmail" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-04 16:41:01 -0300
Processing by InvitesController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"error_message"=>"not_authorized", "importer"=>"gmail"}
  Rendered invites/failure.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]

As the authorization is done?

Thanks for the help!